# Dependent field not getting deployed in Salesforce

Tags: deployment, workbench

I am trying to deploy dependent fields and controlling in salesforce. The deployment is successful via workbench , however the changes in field dependency are not getting impacted in the org. The meta data which is present in retrieve unpacked is not impacting on the target org.In my package.xml I am send the dependent field , controlling field and record types of case object. The extra dependent fields are not getting removed.
How do i resolve this?